# Trying to design Facebook-like notification in mongoose. Need help aggregating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Like Facebook, I would like to aggregate the results. But I can't figure out how to go about it.

Example:

Let's say 10 users like my posts.
I don't want to get 10 notifications. 1 is of course enough.

This is my schema:

```
var eventLogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //i.e. Somebody commented, sombody liked, etc.
    event: String, 

    //to a comment, to a post, to a profile, etc.
    toWhat: String, 

    //who is the user we need to notify?
    toWho: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}, 

    //post id, comment id, whatever.. 
    refID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},         

    //who initiated the event.
    whoDid: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 

    // when the event happened
    date: {type:Date, default: Date.now()},

    //whether the user already saw this notification or not.
    seen: {type:Boolean, default: false}     
    })
```

so I need to count the times

```
Ex.1: event='liked' and toWhat="post" and refID=myPostID and seen=false
```

But at the same time, I would like to populate the last event with this parameters on the 'who' path so I could display "Michael and 9 other people liked your post(link to post)"

Every way I can think of doing this is clunky and requires multiple queries that feel like they would cost a lot of system resources and I am wondering if there's a simple way to do it.

Actually it gets more complicated then that.

I do not want to specify values like I did in Ex.1. 
Instead I would like to say

```
aggregate all events with similar 'event', 'toWhat', 
'refID' with value seen=false and populate the last one on the 'who' path.
```

Would love some reading materials, links, advice, or anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it like this.

Not sure if it's optimal, but it works.

```
//The name of my Schema
Notification.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                //I only want to display new notifications
                seen: {$ne: true}
                //to query a specific user add
                // toWho: UserID
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                //groups when event, toWhat, and refID are similar
                _id: {
                    event: '$event',
                    toWhat: '$toWhat',
                    refID: '$refID',

                },
                //gets the total number of this type of notification
                howMany: {$sum: 1},
                //gets the date of the last document in this query
                date: {$max: '$date'},
                //pulls the user ID of the last user in this query
                user: {$last: '$whoDid'}
            }
        }

    ]).exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results) {
            //after I get the results, I want to populate my user to get his name.
            Notification.populate(results, {path: 'user', model: "User"}, function (err, notifications) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (notifications) res.send(notifications);
            })
        }

    })
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to populate the aggregated result in one query, I assume that if it's possible it would be optimal, but so far, this seems acceptable for my needs.

Hope this helps.